# Apache virtual host for browsing with IP address

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

I'm using virtual host. but I want that when user browses IP address, my server will serve resource in local host. The content of my virtual host config:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

# for main web
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
   DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.6:80>
   DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents
</VirtualHost>

#for other webs
...
```

When user type 192.168.1.6 in the browser, the resource in /Library/WebServer/Documents will be return. But I don't want to designate 192.168.1.6 explicitly, I want something like *.*.*.*

I changed

```
...
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.6:80>
       DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents
</VirtualHost>
...
```

to

```
...
<VirtualHost *.*.*.*:80>
       DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents
</VirtualHost>
...
```

but it don't work.

What should I change? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am personally using this one for IP Vhost 
`NameVirtualHost *:80`
`<VirtualHost *:80>`
`ServerAdmin contact@steelbrain.com.pk`
`DocumentRoot /var/www/ipbased/`
`ServerName 192.168.1.1`
`ServerAlias 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2`
`</VirtualHost>`